# Removeing Phone & Calendar from AOSP(4.4)

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-source

I am trying to remove calendar and phone apps+services from my kit kat aosp build..

I have followed this link [Removing AOSP apps from build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19540017/removing-aosp-apps-from-build)

but so far able to remove gallery and calculator but not able to remove phone and calendar apps/services from it.

After my android boots up doing process list shows com.android.phone, com.android.calendar in list.

I have also tried to modify systemserver.java file but it didnt work as well.

Anybody have shed some good lights here,

Thanks,JRC