# How to set custom launcher as default launcher into ANDROID AOSP source code

Tags: android, android-layout, embedded-linux, android-source

I am creating a custom launcher in my embedded android development board.How to set custom launcher as default launcher into **ANDROID AOSP** source code.

Please help me.

Thanks.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set the default launcher in an AOSP build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22911156/how-do-i-set-the-default-launcher-in-an-aosp-build)

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple solution could be to remove any other launchers from the system, I've listed a couple of ways you could achieve this below.

- A simple way to achieve your goal would be to remove any other launchers from your AOSP source and Android should load up whatever launcher you added. [Information on removing apps from AOSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19540017/removing-aosp-apps-from-build)
- If you already have the system deployed you can delete the original launcher(s), I've added some sample adb commands which should get you where you want to be(You might have to change the name of the launcher depending on what launcher you're trying to remove)

```
adb root
adb remount
adb shell "rm -r /system/app/Launcher3"
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Android.mk` of your application, you need to override all default Launcher applications of AOSP. Like that:

```
LOCAL_OVERRIDES_PACKAGES += Home Launcher2 Launcher3 Launcher3QuickStep CarLauncher
```